# Nodejs execute function weekly

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Only need a simple alternative to weekly job scheduling in Node

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785736/is-there-a-job-scheduler-library-for-node-js) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306090/running-a-function-everyday-midnight#), but I don't understand how can i use them in my case.

I simple want to execute function `executeMeWeeklyAt1200PMMonday()`. Is there a simple an easier way to do it? If not then can someone help me using any existing library to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the library [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) like this:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 0 12 * * 1', executeMeWeeklyAt1200PMMonday, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

That will call the function `executeMeWeeklyAt1200PMMonday` every Monday at noon in Los Angeles. Change 'America/Los_Angeles` to the timezone you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can easly use this : https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 05 08 * * 0', function() {
  /*
   * This function is executed every Synday at 8:05
   */
   executeMeWeeklyAt1200PMMonday();
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```